# Show box plot of one column against values from another column as x axis

Tags: r, bar-chart, histogram, boxplot

I have data that looks as follows

```
"","Speaker","Total"
"1","David",19
"2","Grimes",29
```

I am looking to create a box plot in R as follows
[image]

I am able to create a box plot as follows

```
df = read.csv('C:\\abovefile.csv')
barplot(df$Total, main="Total v/s Speaker",xlab="Speaker name")
```

However, I wasn't able to figure out how to show the name of the speaker at the bottom of each bar. How can I do this in R?

My graph currently looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the names argument in barplot:

```
df <- tibble(
    x = c("1","2"),
    Speaker = c("David", "Grimes"),
    Total = c(19,29)
)

barplot(df$Total, main="Total v/s Speaker",xlab="Speaker name",
        names = df$Speaker)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Plot
ggplot(data,aes(x=Speaker,y=Total))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black',fill='blue')
```

[image]